# About the ratio $(a+b)/n$ for positive integers $a<n$ and $b=a^{-1}$ modulo $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a,n$ be positive integers with $a<n$ and $(a,n)=1$, and let $b<n$ be the unique inverse of $a$ modulo $n$. Then obviously we have $2/n<(a+b)/n<(2n-2)/n$. In particular $0<(a+b)/n<2$.

Suppose we have real numbers $x,y$ with $0<x<y<2$. Can we find (or characterize) all pairs $(n,a)$ with $x<(a+b)/n<y$, if $y-x$ is sufficiently small? Or are there too many (in the sense that it is hard to characterize) pairs $(n,a)$ with $x<(a+b)/n<y$ for arbitrarily small $y-x$? Since in general there is no way to write $b$ as a formula(?) of $a$ and $n$, I can't find a way to handle the ratio $(a+b)/n$

Comment: Given $x,y,n$, there are about $ny$ feasible choices of $a$ (i.e., such that $\frac an<y$). For each $a$, at most about $(y-x)n$ choices of $b$ make $x<\frac{a+b}n<y$. Roughly speaking, for random $a,b$, the probability that $ab\equiv 1\pmod n$ is less than $\frac1n$. So we expect the number of solutions for given $n$ to be bounded by $(y-x)n$.

Comment: it might be easier to consider $k = \frac{ab-1}n$ instead of $b$ directly

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So do you mean that for fixed $n$ the number of such pairs $(a,b)$ will increase as $n$ increases?

Comment: @CommandMaster How can we substitue $k$ in $(a+b)/n$?